# "message": "Unauthorized Access" is showing, get method is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server

when I post this method in my MongoDB database it's working properly, but when I wanted to get it it's showing {"message": "Unauthorized Access"} in my http://localhost:5000/my site. The thing which I wanted everything is ok. But get is not working

//server side code

```
 app.post("/my", async (req, res) => {
        const my = req.body;
        const result = await myCollection.insertOne(my);
        res.send(result);
      });
      app.get("/my", async (req, res) => {
        const query = {};
        const cursor = myCollection.find(query);
        const services = await cursor.toArray();
        res.send(services);
      });
```

//client side code

```
 const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/service`;
        fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => {
            setIsReload(!isReload);
            if (result) {
              alert("Add Successful");
            }
          });
        const order = {
          email: user.email,
          name: event.target.name.value,
          description: event.target.description.value,
          price: event.target.price.value,
          quantity: event.target.quantity.value,
        };
        axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/my`, order).then((res) => {
          const { data } = res;
          console.log(data);
          if (data.insertedId) {
            alert("Inserted");
          }
          event.target.reset();
          console.log(res);
        });
      };
```

Comment: perhaps `req.body` isn't correct ... is it? why are you using both fetch and axios in the client. Doesn't that cause confusion for you?

Comment: Where is the "GET" request in the client code? I see only "POST"...

Comment: David gabrielyan in number 6 line I add get method.  Can you tell me the reason why this is happening, it's gives me pain very much